# Incrementing array indices without loops based on filter 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, increment, indices

I have a 2D array that I need to increment indices based on a flags from another array. The indices that are incremented may be repeated. I can use loops but I want to be efficient.

1-D example:

```
a = np.zeros(10,dtype=np.int)
iflag = [1,3,5,1,1,3,1,7,3,5,1,1]
a[iflag] =+1
```

gives
a
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])

What I want is
a
array([0,6,0,3,0,2,0,1,0,0])

I need to do this in 2D

```
array = np.zeros(400,600)
flag.shape 
 (2000,20)
for i in np.range(20):
  for j in np.range(2000) :
     if (flag[i,j] ==1) : 
# ilat, ilon and flag are all same shape
# ilat and ilon will contain positive int that are indices to array    
        array[ilat[i,j],ilon[i,j]] += 1
```

what I'd like to do is something like:

```
  iflag= np.where(flag ==1)
  array[ilat[iflag],ilon[iflag]] += 1
```

Comment: For 1D array, `np.bincount(iflag)` seems to do what you want. I can't quite understand how you index `flag[i,j]` into `td`.

Comment: Hopefully I clarified my intent, edited OP.